# test unit in scala with Json String

Tags: json, scala, unit-testing

I have a method which creates a json object and return the string.
I want to make a unit test on this function but the method return a string like this:

```
{"att1":"{\"scale\": 0, \"significand\": 10}","name":"john","lastname":"smith","job":"developper"}
```

If you copy-paste this line into commas, you don't get a string. And I can't use JSON.parseFull() because again, this is not a String. And I don't want my method to directly return a jsonObject.

I use this kind of object to create my json String

```
val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
val myJson= objectMapper.createObjectNode()
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myJson)
```

And I use this code to make my unit test:

```
class MyJsonTest extends FlatSpec {

  "My method" should "generate a valid json" in {

    val myJsonString = getMyJson() //method to test

    // this is not a valid String but my method return this:
    val correctJson = "{"att1":"{\"scale\": 0, \"significand\": 10}","name":"john","lastname":"smith","job":"developper"}"

    assert(correctJson === myJsonString )

  }
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I would say the created json is not valid since the result string should not contain the escape character '\'.
Validating the json is simple using a raw string since then you don't have to use escape characters and you can do an exact match on the string.
    """{"attr1":{"scale":0, "significant":10}, "name":"John"}"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should interpolate your string by using s""" YOUR_STRING HERE """, to take in consideration your "

```
 class test extends FlatSpec {

  def getSampleJson = """{"att1":"{"scale": 0, "significand": 10}","name":"john","lastname":"smith","job":"developper"}"""

  "My method" should "generate a valid json" in {

    val myJsonString = getSampleJson

    // this is not a valid String but my method return this:
    val correctJson =
      s"""{"att1":"{\"scale\": 0, \"significand\": 10}","name":"john","lastname":"smith","job":"developper"}"""


    println(myJsonString) // {"att1":"{"scale": 0, "significand": 10}","name":"john","lastname":"smith","job":"developper"}

    println(correctJson) // {"att1":"{"scale": 0, "significand": 10}","name":"john","lastname":"smith","job":"developper"}

    assert(correctJson === myJsonString)

  }
}
```

So now, you can just call your method getJson :)

Comment: nice but, how do you call on myMethodToTest() since: s"""myMethodToTest()""" return the string: myMethodToTest()

Comment: No, just do val myJsonString = myMethodToTest() 
without the quotes & it i will work :)

Comment: It doen't work because, s""" remove back slash so I dont have the same string. for exemple I get:
{"att1":"{"scale": 0, "significand": 10}","name":"john","lastname":"smith","job":"developper"}

Comment: I've just update the answer, It works for me, can you please test it and tell what's wrong exactly ?

Comment: I was very stupid (override a toString() creating attributes of my json gave me weird caracter), my fault...
It work very well :)